# How to find the closed path in a digraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The graph

```
g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3,  3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 3 <-> 3}]
```

is associated to the  matrix

```
m = ( {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}  } )
```

The trace of `m^k` gives the number of closed walks of length `k`.
So for `k=2`, `Tr[MatrixPower[m, 2]]` gives 3 closed walks. I want to list those 3 closed walks so I have tried `cw=Table[FindPath[g, i, i, {3}], {i, 3}]`. The computational result is {{},{},{}}. I certainly have made a mistake but I do not see which. Due to comments I have understud my mistake but the question stay open : how to list the closed walks of length `k` ?

Comment: A "walk" may have repeated vertices and edges.  A "path" may not repeat any vertices (or edges).

Comment: Also, the adjacency matrix and the graph you show do not correspond to each other. For the graph the result is 1, specifically the walk `3 -> 3 -> 3`. For the matrix, the result is 3 (not 11), and the walks are `3 -> 2 -> 3`, `2 -> 3 -> 2` and `3 -> 3 ->3`.

Comment: Szabolcs your completely true. 11 is for k= 4. But is there a way to find the walks ?

Comment: Szabolcs I have corrected the graph to correspond to the matrix and modified the nomber of closed walks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us work with a proper directed graph, not a mixed graph, as mixed graphs can get us into a mess.

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 3}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

First we define a more useful `AdjacencyList` which follows only out-edges in directed graphs and returns a full association.

```
adjList[g_?DirectedGraphQ] :=
 AssociationThread[
  VertexList[g],
  VertexList[g][[#]] & /@ AdjacencyMatrix[g]["AdjacencyLists"]
 ]

adjList[g]
(* <|1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> {1, 2, 3}|> *)
```

This function extends an existing walk in all possible ways based on an adjacency list.

```
extend[al_][walk_] := Append[walk, #] & /@ al@Last[walk]
```

For example, if we are currently in node 3, we can end up in nodes 1, 2 or 3.

```
extend[adjList[g]][{2, 3}]
(* {{2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}} *)
```

Generate all walks of length 3:

```
Nest[
 Catenate[extend[adjList[g]] /@ #] &,
 {{1}, {2}, {3}},
 3
 ]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2}, {2,
   3, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 2, 
  3}, {3, 2, 3, 1}, {3, 2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 
  2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}} *)
```

Which are cyclic?

```
Cases[%, {s_, ___, s_}]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 3}, {3,
   2, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Szabolcs, I thank you very much for your contribution. But what could I do if there are loops ? Your solution doesn't work

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Can you give an example where it does not work?

Comment: g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 3 <-> 3}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]

Comment: Sorry I am really tired my exemple is a mess.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Don't use a mixed graph. The input must be a directed graph. All edges must be directed.  Don't use `<->` in the input.